# Adding functions in .cshrc in C-Shell

Tags: function, shell, command-line

I want to add custom functions in my **.cshrc** file to execute some functionality with some inputs through my command line. I'm using C-shell. is there any way I could implement this or any work around to get the desired result?

Answer (score 4):

C Shell doesnt support functions.

I suggest you can create scripts to emulate the functions and then use alias in the .cshrc file to call those scripts when you type your command in the command line.

e.g , i want to define a new command called test in my csh environment.
So i would add the below line in the .cshrc file

```
alias test "${HOME}/.test.sh"
```

Now i would create a .test.sh script in my ${HOME} directory ( or whereever you want it to be) and put the logic for the command inside the script.

An example as follows:

```
/home/abis> cat .test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo $1 $2
```

Then i would give execute permission to the .test.sh script and source the .cshrc file( it would be done anyway when you open a new login shell).

Then when i execute the command from the command line , the actual script would be called.

```
/home/abis> test "Hello" "World"
Hello World
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement the above answer for a task ... in one command create a directory and enter to that directory . so i wrote a script like test.tcl   ...........                eval mkdir $1 \n
                                                         eval cd $1                            and i'm running with the help of alias. It creates the directory but the second line doesn't work ... u have any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc`:

```
alias function '( set argv = ( \!* ) ; source ~/.cshfuncs )'
```

Define your functions in `.cshfuncs`:

```
# Functions for C Shell.

switch ("$1")
  case "myfunc":
    echo "A function."
    exit
  case "myfunc2":
    echo "Another function."
    exit
  default:
    echo "Function $1 not set."
    exit -1
endsw
```